# How to make timeout/exit from a Kafka-node consumer if no message received within specified-time

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have written a Kafka-node consumer. This works absolutely fine if there is any message available in the topic but gets blocked forever if there is no new message available in the topic. I want to close the consumer and call a callback function if no message is received within specified time-frame of 10 seconds. Is there a way to handle this scenario in nodejs?

Comment: Hi @Ayan can you please share code snippet, and are you using node-rdkafka?

Comment: Consumers are generally meant to run forever, not block other code that would run "after consumption"

Comment: @RaviChaudhary I am using node-kafka of nodejs module

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample of consumer i created with schema registry integrated:

> You need to register disconnected event

```
this.consumer.on("disconnected", this.disconnected.bind(this));

private disconnected(arg) {
    this.connect();
}
```

> Code Snippet

```
const AVROSchemaRegistry = require("avro-schema-registry");
import { KafkaConsumer } from "node-rdkafka";


export class Consumer {
private consumer;
private brokerList;
private schemaRegistry;
private topics;
private groupId;
private consumerAmount = 15;
private consumerIntervalMs = 1000;
private callBack;

/**
 * Gets the Consumer singleton instance. If it wasn"t created, first creates the instance then returns that instance.
 * @param brokerList List of brokerList in the Kafka cluster ("," separated)
 * @param consumerGroup Array of consumer groups and their topics
 * @param callBack Callback function that will run when a new event is received
 * @return Consumer
 */
constructor(brokerList, schemaRegistry, consumerGroup, callBack) {
    this.brokerList = brokerList;
    this.schemaRegistry = schemaRegistry;
    this.topics = consumerGroup.topics;
    this.groupId = consumerGroup.id;
    this.callBack = callBack;
}

public async init(cb) {
    if(!this.consumer) {
    //KAFKA CONSUMER CONFIG
    const config = {
        "metadata.broker.list": this.brokerList,
        ...(this.groupId && { "group.id": this.groupId }),
    };


    this.consumer = new KafkaConsumer(config);

    this.consumer.on("event.log", this.eventLog.bind(this));
    this.consumer.on("event.error", this.eventError.bind(this));
    this.consumer.on("ready", this.ready.bind(this));
    this.consumer.on("data", this.data.bind(this));
    this.consumer.on("disconnected", this.disconnected.bind(this));

    this.connect();
    }
}

private connect(cb) {
    if(this.consumer) {
    // KAFKA CONSUMER CONNECTING...

    this.consumer.connect(undefined, (err, data) => {
        if(err) {
        // KAFKA CONSUMER CONNECTION ERROR
        } else {
        // KAFKA CONSUMER CONNECTED
        if(cb) {
            cb(err, data);
        }
        }
    });
    }
}

private eventLog(log) {
    // log("KAFKA CONSUMER EVENT LOG:", JSON.stringify(log));
}

private eventError(eventErr) {
    // log("KAFKA CONSUMER EVENT ERROR:", JSON.stringify(eventErr));
}

private ready(arg) {
    // log("KAFKA CONSUMER READY:", JSON.stringify(arg));
    this.consumer.subscribe(this.topics);
    setInterval(() => {
    this.consumer.consume(this.consumerAmount);
    }, this.consumerIntervalMs);
}

private async data(message) {
    // KAFKA CONSUMER RECEIVED DATA message and DECODED MESSAGE VALUE
    const messageValue = await AVROSchemaRegistry(this.schemaRegistry).decode(message.value);

    if(this.callBack) {
    this.callBack(null, {
        value: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(messageValue)), 
        key: message.key ? message.key.toString() : null
    });
    }
}

private disconnected(arg) {
    // KAFKA CONSUMER DISCONNECTED RECONNECT AGAIN
    this.connect();
}

}
```